# High test accuracy but low performance on new samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, svm

am working on an image classification application and get good results about 97% test accuracy but when I test the trained model on a new unseen sample the model failed to predict the right class whats might be the problem?

```
No_of_Features = 508
filePath='cb10.csv'
k='all'    
#param_grid = {'C': [0.1,1, 10, 100], 'gamma': ['auto'],'kernel': ['linear','rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid']}
param_grid = {'C': [1], 'gamma': ['auto'],'kernel': ['linear']}
def select_features(X_train,y_train,X_test):
     fs = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=k)
     fs.fit(X_train, y_train)     
     X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
     X_test_fs  = fs.transform(X_test)
     return X_train_fs,X_test_fs,fs 
data = pd.read_csv(filePath) 
d=data.values
X = d[:,0:No_of_Features-1]
y = d[:,No_of_Features]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
X_train_fs, X_test_fs, fs =select_features(X_train,y_train,X_test)
model = GridSearchCV(SVC(),param_grid,cv=5,refit=True,verbose=2,n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X_train_fs, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_fs)

print('Best GridSearchCV parameters: ',model.best_params_)
print("Accuracy: ",accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

[image: this is the accuracy and confusion matrix]

this is what I do to predict the new samples

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv') 
d=data.values
X = d[:,0:No_of_Features-1]
xfs = fs.transform(X)
z = model.predict(xfs)
print(z)
```

knowing that the features are extracted the the same exact ways and sometimes I cut some of the training file features and also fails to predict

Comment: How bad is the confusion matrix on the test set?

Comment: why do you think its bad?

Comment: I didn’t say that it is bad, I am just trying to understand the problem a bit better. When you say: “the model does not perform well on the test set“ … how much worse is it? On how many samples do you test it? Is the distribution (at least of the target variable) the same on the Test set (in comparison to the distribution on the training set)? All these questions need to be answered.

Comment: I see, I have two classes 1 , and 0 no matter how much data I put in the model its all classified as 1's

Comment: That is weird indeed... wat happens if you replace `data = pd.read_csv('test.csv') ` with `data = pd.read_csv(filePath)` in the very last paragraph (i.e. test the model on the training data again)?

Comment: And what happens if you only do one test example and manipuly this single example so that it comes closer and closer to a known example where the model produces 0? And how do the "probabilistic predictions" look like (i.e. the prediction that is a number between 0 and 1 that is being turned into a boolean prediction by saying that this number is higher than a threshold)?